# ACCESS 2010 Create identical table with values replaced using formula

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query to create a new table which from the existing table with all values replaced as a % of total.

## Existing table

```
ID NAME VALUE1 VALUE2 TOTAL
1  A     4     6       10
2  B     4     8       12
```

## NEW TABLE

```
ID NAME  VALUE1   VALUE2    TOTAL
1  A     40.00%   60.00%    100.00%
2  B     33.33%   66.67%    100.00%
```

Comment: I'm looking at the old table and then the new and wondering where `B` went, and how you got `33.33%` for the second `A` record in the new table....Very confusing.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that he intended to put B there instead of A for the second record.  Not sure if you're serious about the 33.33%, but 4/12 would give you that.  The new Total column is unnecessary though, as I'm not seeing where it would not be 100%.

Comment: Each record is independent of each other. there are actually more column for the values, horizentally, adding all the % would give 100%,

Comment: @Lunyx It's pretty obvious? Really? Well then I suppose it's pretty obvious how the total column is necessary if we're operating within your logical capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using the sample data you've given, we can accomplish this fairly easily by using what you already have and a little formatting.

```
SELECT pct.Name, 
Format([Value1]/[Total],"Percent") AS Value_1, 
Format([Value2]/[Total],"Percent") AS Value_2,
 Format(1,"Percent") AS Total_New 
INTO NewTbl
FROM pct;
```

Replace `pct` with your table name.